# Simulate keypress jquery on function

Tags: jquery, keypress, keycode

I want to simulate the up keypress (number 40) on a certain function using jquery.

So basically:

```
function simulate_up() {
    // code to simulate up key (key code 40)
}
```

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

See this;

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 40;
$("your_slector").trigger(press);
```

From [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simulating-keypress-events).

Comment: Thanks but in this case a selector triggers the keypress. I just want a function that triggers the keypress.

Comment: Shloudn't events be applied on elements rather than functions..?

Comment: Yes I know it isn't a nice solution, but I wanted it to use a quick hack to communicate between 2 different javascript files. So the keypress triggers a function in another javascript file, not even sure if it can work!